# pythonic method for extracting numeric digits from string

Tags: python, python-re

I am developing a program to read through a CSV file and create a dictionary of information from it. Each line in the CSV is essentially a new dictionary entry with the delimited objects being the values.

As one subpart of task, I need to extract an unknown number of numeric digits from within a string. I have a working version, but it does not seem very pythonic.

An example string looks like this:

`variable = Applicaiton.Module_Name.VAR_NAME_ST12.WORD_type[0]`

`variable` is string's name in the python code, and represents the variable name within a MODBUS. I want to extract just the digits prior to the **.WORD_type[0]** which relate to the number of bytes the string is packed into.

Here is my working code, note this is nested within a for statement iterating through the lines in the CSV. `var_length` and `var_type` are some of the `keys`, i.e. `{"var_length": var_length}`

```
if re.search(".+_ST[0-9]{1,2}\\.WORD_type.+", variable):
    var_type = "string"
    temp = re.split("\\.", variable)
    temp = re.split("_", temp[2])
    temp = temp[-1]
    var_length = int(str.lstrip(temp, "ST")) / 2
```

Comment: This is most definitely an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info). Ask what you are actually trying to achieve and show the actual input and required output. `csv.DictReader` and `str.isdigit` can probably do most of the heavy-lifting.

Comment: You say that there is an "unknown number of numeric digits" but your regex limits it to either 1 or 2 digits. It is also not clear if the name of the variable is `variable` or if `variable` is in fact part of the string.

Comment: @DeepSpace, I am unable to use the `csv` module as the modules available on the device are limited. There are also instances where there can be other digits in the string.

Comment: @Selcuk I am limiting it to 2 digits at this point, as these actually correspond to the number of bytes that the variable is packed into in a MODBUS.

Comment: Why can't you simply use your existing regex with a capturing group, e.g. `print(re.search(".+_ST([0-9]{1,2})\\.WORD_type.+", variable).groups())` instead of trying to parse the string again, using splits and slices?

Comment: The `csv` module is built-in, just like `re` is.

Comment: can you post sample csv text with some of the trickier input values?

Comment: @DeepSpace in the application I am working in, not all modules are included in the python build. Unfortunately CSV is one of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could maybe try using matching groups like so:

```
import re

variable = "Applicaiton.Module_Name.VAR_NAME_ST12.WORD_type[0]"
matches = re.match(r".+_ST(\d+)\.WORD_type.+", variable)
if matches:
    print(matches[1])
```

`matches[0]` has the full match and `matches[1]` contains the matched group.